# UserCredential class from google apis not found

Tags: c#, google-api, youtube-api, google-api-dotnet-client

Im using ms vs express 2012 win desktop and trying to compile this code example https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet#upload_a_video

I got nuget packages like Google.Apis.YouTube.v3, Google.Apis.Authentication and Google APIs Client Library. Now I got couple hundreds dlls, some of them is duplicating.

Added following references

[image]

My using directives:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Google.Apis;

using Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.DotNetOpenAuth;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Upload;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using Google.Apis.YouTube;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data;
```

Compilation fails with following errors:

> UserCredential can not be found (missing using directive?)
>
> GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker does not exist
>
> GoogleClientSecrets does not exist

What reference or using directive do I need? GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker seems to require Google.Apis.Auth.PlatformServices - I have Google.Apis.Authenication.PlatformServices reference, doesn't helps.

Comment: did you add all the using's in your code that are in the tutorial?

Comment: technically speaking you only need to add the single package and it will add everything you need for you PM>  Install-Package Google.Apis.YouTube.v3

Comment: @DaImTo yes just copied everything. Well it downloaded a lot of files and folders, a lot of different version of same dll, I added several of them but looks like something is still missing. 509 different dll files

Comment: I think something is up it shouldn't download that many

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We stopped using DotNetOpenAuth and Google.Apis.Authentication (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Authentication/ is obsolete) almost 3 years ago. Notice that the sample in https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet#upload_a_video actually uses the right usings.

I recommend you cleaning your project and reinstall the YouTube NuGet package, it will install all the right dependencies for you.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is a different version of some dlls, some of them have Google.Apis.Authentication structure while other one have Google.Apis.**Auth**, so you need to find one with Auth and code will compile!